# change group height dynamically

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report with multiple groups. sometimes in some groups all field's value will be null.
in that situation, I wanna this group's height become less to fit.
What can I do?

Comment: when you say all fields, do you mean in the details section?

Comment: Would suppressing, or hiding the section altogether, if it contains some criteria [eg. all values are null] be good enough?

Comment: it think it's enough, but I don't know How can I do it by code!

Answer (score 2):

You've got a few options.. but it maybe just be simpler to remove the null records from the dataset using the 'selection expert' or amending your data source/command, SQL?

Alternatively you can look at the 'Format Editor' using formulas to 'Suppress' individual fields and in the 'Section Expert' tick 'Suppress blank sections' for the details, headers and footers.

Would that solve your problem?

Comment: thanks a lot, your solution answered. I just tick suppress blank sections, and it solved.

Comment: @user422481 If you tick the arrow to accept answers, people will be more inclined to answer your questions. Cheers, Ears.